# Handling negetive index in difference equation of IIR filter

Tags: c, signal-processing

I need to implement this difference equation (of IIR filter) in C.

```
int a[3]={ 1 , -1 ,  2 };
int b[3]={1,2,3}
int in[100]=some numbers;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    y[i]=(b[0]*in1[i])+(b[1]*in[i-1])+(b[2]*in[i-2])-(a[1]*y[i-1])-(a[2]*y[i-2]); `
```

I need to make `in[-ve index]=0`. How to handle this difference equation?
I cannot use `if` statements because it's being implemented in a DSP.

Also can anyone suggest hold to implement a circular buffer using pointers in c, which will help my cause here.

Comment: _i-2_ sure your _i_ start from 2

Answer (score 2):

First do the calculation for the first two entries in the `in` array, where you substitute zero for the entries with negative indexes, then loop from 2 instead.

```
y[0]=(b[0]*in1[0])+(b[1]*0)    +(b[2]*0)-(a[1]*0)   -(a[2]*0);
y[1]=(b[0]*in1[1])+(b[1]*in[0])+(b[2]*0)-(a[1]*y[0])-(a[2]*0);
for (int i = 2; i < 100; ++i)
   ...
```

Since you're doing a couple of multiplications with zero, those calculations can of course be shortened.

---

As for circular buffer, just make an array of a fixed size, and a continually increasing index which you then use the modulo operation to limit.

So

```
int *circular[10];  /* A ten-entry circular buffer for integer pointers */
int circularIndex = 0;

/* Adding a new entry */
circular[circularIndex] = somePointer;
circularIndex = (circularIndex + 1) % 10;  /* Make sure the index goes from 0 to 9 */
```

Comment: The first suggestion is not feasible. If i want to test for higher order filters(consider 5th order), I cannot keep adding separate sentences for y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4]. Thanks for the circular buffer example. Can u suggest a delay line buffer method to implement IIR filter (for the above difference equation)?